# Delegate method is not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I am sure this question has been asked many times and I saw all those solutions but I was not able to figure out why my delegate method is not called.

I have two view controllers, let's say Viewcontroller1 and ViewController2. My ViewController2 is loaded first. I have ViewController1 as a part of SWRevealViewController. When I click the button on ViewController I want to run the method on ViewController2 but it is not doing so,

//In ViewController 1.

```
@protocol Company ;
#import "ViewController2.h"

@protocol Company <NSObject>
@required -(void) companyChange : (NSString *) sample;

@end


@interface ViewController1 : UITableViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>
@property (weak,nonatomic) id<Company> delegate;
@end


-(void) buttonClicked {
 [self.delegate companyChange:@"Hello"];
}
```

Let's say I want to print @"Hello" in ViewController2.

I need to import ViewController2 for other purpose.

//In ViewController2

```
#import "ViewController1.h"

extern NSString * const firstString ;
@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController <Company>


 -(void) viewDidLoad {
ViewController *vc1 = [[ViewController1 alloc]init];
    vc1.delegate = self;
}
```

//This method is never called

```
- (void) companyChange:(NSString *)sample {
    NSLog(@"%@",sample);
}
```

//There is also warning that Company protocol is not defined.

//I have connected buttonClicked method to a button and the ViewController1 is SWRevealController menu . 
I am not able to figure out what is wrong with the code.

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside `buttonClicked`.  What is the value of `self.delegate` when you hit the breakpoint?

Comment: The instance of `ViewController1` you are creating in `viewDidLoad` and setting the delegate on is not the same instance that is being shown in your app. It's a new instance that gets deallocated immediately afterwards.

Comment: @PhillipMills the  in the ViewController2  -(void) companyChange : (NSString *) sample is not called but the [self.delegate companyChange:@"Hello"] is called.

Comment: @dan how can I go about fixing it?

Comment: @Rosh I understood that from your question.  What did you see when you set the breakpoint?

Comment: @PhillipMills thanks. I was lost within my code. I was calling the delegate method within the delegate instead of from the delegatee. I was doing it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SWRevealViewController you don't really need to use delegation. You can use the convenience function revealViewController to get a reference to the SWRevealViewController, if you #import "SWRevealViewController.h". Then you can say something like:

```
    SWRevealViewController *myRevealViewController = [self revealViewController];
    UIViewController *frontViewController = myRevealViewController.frontViewController;
    frontViewController.text = @"Something I Want to Show on Screen";
```

Or

```
    SWRevealViewController *myRevealViewController = [self revealViewController];
    UIViewController *backViewController = myRevealViewController.backViewController;
    backViewController.text = @"Something I Want to Show on Screen";
```

Where text is a public NSString property.